# unordered_set: a hash table -based set data structure in C89

Tags: c, hash-map, set, c89

In this post, I present a hash table -based set data structure written in C89:

**`unordered_set.h`**

```
#ifndef UNORDERED_SET_H
#define UNORDERED_SET_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct unordered_set {
        struct unordered_set_state* state;
    } unordered_set;

    typedef struct unordered_set_iterator unordered_set_iterator;

    /***************************************************************************
    * Allocates a new, empty set with given hash function and given equality   *
    * testing function.                                                        *
    ***************************************************************************/
    unordered_set* unordered_set_alloc(size_t initial_capacity,
        float load_factor,
        size_t(*p_hash_function)(void*),
        int (*p_equals_function)(void*, void*));

    /***************************************************************************
    * Adds 'p_element' to the set if not already there. Returns true if the    *
    * structure of the set changed.                                            *
    ***************************************************************************/
    int  unordered_set_add(unordered_set* p_set, void* p_element);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns true if the set contains the element.                            *
    ***************************************************************************/
    int  unordered_set_contains(unordered_set* p_set, void* p_element);

    /***************************************************************************
    * If the element is in the set, removes it and returns true.               *
    ***************************************************************************/
    int  unordered_set_remove(unordered_set* p_set, void* p_element);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Removes all the contents of the set.                                     *
    ***************************************************************************/
    void   unordered_set_clear(unordered_set* p_set);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the size of the set.                                             *
    ***************************************************************************/
    size_t unordered_set_size(unordered_set* p_set);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Checks that the set is in valid state.                                   *
    ***************************************************************************/
    int unordered_set_is_healthy(unordered_set* p_set);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Deallocates the entire set. Only the set and its nodes are deallocated.  *
    * The user is responsible for deallocating the actual data stored in the   *
    * set.                                                                     *
    ***************************************************************************/
    void unordered_set_free(unordered_set* p_set);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the iterator over the set. The nodes are iterated in insertion   *
    * order.                                                                   *
    ***************************************************************************/
    unordered_set_iterator* unordered_set_iterator_alloc(unordered_set* p_set);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the number of elements not yet iterated over.                    *
    ***************************************************************************/
    size_t unordered_set_iterator_has_next(unordered_set_iterator* p_iterator);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Loads the next element in the iteration order. Returns true if advanced  *
    * to the next element.                                                     *
    ***************************************************************************/
    int unordered_set_iterator_next(unordered_set_iterator* p_iterator,
        void** pp_element);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns true if the set was modified during the iteration.               *
    ***************************************************************************/
    int unordered_set_iterator_is_disturbed(unordered_set_iterator* p_iterator);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Deallocates the set iterator.                                            *
    ***************************************************************************/
    void unordered_set_iterator_free(unordered_set_iterator* p_iterator);

    /* Contains the unit tests. */
    void unordered_set_test();

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* UNORDERED_SET_H */
```

**`unordered_set.c`**

```
#include "my_assert.h"
#include "unordered_set.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

typedef struct unordered_set_entry {
    void*                       key;
    struct unordered_set_entry* chain_next;
    struct unordered_set_entry* prev;
    struct unordered_set_entry* next;
} unordered_set_entry;

typedef struct unordered_set_state {
    unordered_set_entry**  table;
    unordered_set_entry*   head;
    unordered_set_entry*   tail;
    size_t (*hash_function)(void*);
    int (*equals_function) (void*, void*);
    size_t                 mod_count;
    size_t                 table_capacity;
    size_t                 size;
    size_t                 mask;
    size_t                 max_allowed_size;
    float                  load_factor;
} unordered_set_state;

struct unordered_set_iterator {
    unordered_set*       set;
    unordered_set_entry* next_entry;
    size_t               iterated_count;
    size_t               expected_mod_count;
};

static unordered_set_entry* unordered_set_entry_alloc(void* key)
{
    unordered_set_entry* entry = malloc(sizeof(*entry));

    if (!entry)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    entry->key = key;
    entry->chain_next = NULL;
    entry->next = NULL;
    entry->prev = NULL;

    return entry;
}

static const float  MINIMUM_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.2f;
static const int MINIMUM_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

static float maxf(float a, float b)
{
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

static int maxi(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Makes sure that the load factor is no less than a minimum threshold.         *
*******************************************************************************/
static float fix_load_factor(float load_factor)
{
    return maxf(load_factor, MINIMUM_LOAD_FACTOR);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Makes sure that the initial capacity is no less than a minimum allowed and   *
* is a power of two.                                                           *
*******************************************************************************/
static size_t fix_initial_capacity(size_t initial_capacity)
{
    size_t ret;

    initial_capacity = maxi(initial_capacity, MINIMUM_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    ret = 1;

    while (ret < initial_capacity)
    {
        ret <<= 1;
    }

    return ret;
}

unordered_set* unordered_set_alloc(size_t initial_capacity,
    float load_factor,
    size_t(*hash_function)(void*),
    int (*equals_function)(void*, void*))
{
    unordered_set* set;

    if (!hash_function || !equals_function)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    set = malloc(sizeof(*set));

    if (!set)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    set->state = malloc(sizeof(*set->state));
    load_factor = fix_load_factor(load_factor);
    initial_capacity = fix_initial_capacity(initial_capacity);

    set->state->load_factor = load_factor;
    set->state->table_capacity = initial_capacity;
    set->state->size = 0;
    set->state->mod_count = 0;
    set->state->head = NULL;
    set->state->tail = NULL;
    set->state->table = calloc(initial_capacity,
        sizeof(unordered_set_entry*));
    set->state->hash_function = hash_function;
    set->state->equals_function = equals_function;
    set->state->mask = initial_capacity - 1;
    set->state->max_allowed_size = (size_t)(initial_capacity * load_factor);

    return set;
}

static void ensure_capacity(unordered_set* set)
{
    size_t new_capacity;
    size_t new_mask;
    size_t index;
    unordered_set_entry*  entry;
    unordered_set_entry** new_table;

    if (set->state->size < set->state->max_allowed_size)
    {
        return;
    }

    new_capacity = 2 * set->state->table_capacity;
    new_mask = new_capacity - 1;
    new_table = calloc(new_capacity, sizeof(unordered_set_entry*));

    if (!new_table)
    {
        return;
    }

    /* Rehash the entries. */
    for (entry = set->state->head; entry; entry = entry->next)
    {
        index = set->state->hash_function(entry->key) & new_mask;
        entry->chain_next = new_table[index];
        new_table[index] = entry;
    }

    free(set->state->table);

    set->state->table = new_table;
    set->state->table_capacity = new_capacity;
    set->state->mask = new_mask;
    set->state->max_allowed_size = (size_t)(new_capacity * set->state->load_factor);
}

int unordered_set_add(unordered_set* set, void* key)
{
    size_t index;
    size_t hash_value;
    unordered_set_entry* entry;

    if (!set)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hash_value = set->state->hash_function(key);
    index = hash_value & set->state->mask;

    for (entry = set->state->table[index]; entry; entry = entry->chain_next)
    {
        if (set->state->equals_function(entry->key, key))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    ensure_capacity(set);

    /* Recompute the index since it is possibly changed by 'ensure_capacity' */
    index = hash_value & set->state->mask;
    entry = unordered_set_entry_alloc(key);
    entry->chain_next = set->state->table[index];
    set->state->table[index] = entry;

    /* Link the new entry to the tail of the list. */
    if (!set->state->tail)
    {
        set->state->head = entry;
        set->state->tail = entry;
    }
    else
    {
        set->state->tail->next = entry;
        entry->prev = set->state->tail;
        set->state->tail = entry;
    }

    set->state->size++;
    set->state->mod_count++;

    return true;
}

int unordered_set_contains(unordered_set* set, void* key)
{
    size_t index;
    unordered_set_entry* p_entry;

    if (!set)
    {
        return false;
    }

    index = set->state->hash_function(key) & set->state->mask;

    for (p_entry = set->state->table[index]; p_entry; p_entry = p_entry->chain_next)
    {
        if (set->state->equals_function(key, p_entry->key))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int unordered_set_remove(unordered_set* set, void* key)
{
    size_t index;
    unordered_set_entry* prev_entry;
    unordered_set_entry* current_entry;

    if (!set)
    {
        return false;
    }

    index = set->state->hash_function(key) & set->state->mask;

    prev_entry = NULL;

    for (current_entry = set->state->table[index];
        current_entry;
        current_entry = current_entry->chain_next)
    {
        if (set->state->equals_function(key, current_entry->key))
        {
            if (prev_entry)
            {
                /* Omit the 'p_current_entry' in the collision chain. */
                prev_entry->chain_next = current_entry->chain_next;
            }
            else
            {
                set->state->table[index] = current_entry->chain_next;
            }

            /* Unlink from the global iteration chain. */
            if (current_entry->prev)
            {
                current_entry->prev->next = current_entry->next;
            }
            else
            {
                set->state->head = current_entry->next;
            }

            if (current_entry->next)
            {
                current_entry->next->prev = current_entry->prev;
            }
            else
            {
                set->state->tail = current_entry->prev;
            }

            set->state->size--;
            set->state->mod_count++;
            free(current_entry);
            return true;
        }

        prev_entry = current_entry;
    }

    return false;
}

void unordered_set_clear(unordered_set* set)
{
    unordered_set_entry* entry;
    unordered_set_entry* next_entry;
    size_t index;

    if (!set)
    {
        return;
    }

    entry = set->state->head;

    while (entry)
    {
        index = set->state->hash_function(entry->key) & set->state->mask;
        next_entry = entry->next;
        free(entry);
        entry = next_entry;
        set->state->table[index] = NULL;
    }

    set->state->mod_count += set->state->size;
    set->state->size = 0;
    set->state->head = NULL;
    set->state->tail = NULL;
}

size_t unordered_set_size(unordered_set* set)
{
    return set ? set->state->size : 0;
}

int unordered_set_is_healthy(unordered_set* set)
{
    size_t counter;
    unordered_set_entry* entry;

    if (!set)
    {
        return false;
    }

    counter = 0;
    entry = set->state->head;

    if (entry && entry->prev)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (; entry; entry = entry->next)
    {
        counter++;
    }

    return counter == set->state->size;
}

void unordered_set_free(unordered_set* set)
{
    if (!set)
    {
        return;
    }

    unordered_set_clear(set);
    free(set->state->table);
    free(set);
}

unordered_set_iterator*
unordered_set_iterator_alloc(unordered_set* set)
{
    unordered_set_iterator* iterator;

    if (!set)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    iterator = malloc(sizeof(*iterator));

    if (!iterator)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    iterator->set = set;
    iterator->iterated_count = 0;
    iterator->next_entry = set->state->head;
    iterator->expected_mod_count = set->state->mod_count;

    return iterator;
}

size_t unordered_set_iterator_has_next(unordered_set_iterator* iterator)
{
    if (!iterator)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (unordered_set_iterator_is_disturbed(iterator))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return iterator->set->state->size - iterator->iterated_count;
}

int unordered_set_iterator_next(unordered_set_iterator* iterator,
    void** key_pointer)
{
    if (!iterator)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!iterator->next_entry)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (unordered_set_iterator_is_disturbed(iterator))
    {
        return false;
    }

    *key_pointer = iterator->next_entry->key;
    iterator->iterated_count++;
    iterator->next_entry = iterator->next_entry->next;

    return true;
}

int unordered_set_iterator_is_disturbed(unordered_set_iterator* iterator)
{
    if (!iterator)
    {
        false;
    }

    return iterator->expected_mod_count != iterator->set->state->mod_count;
}

void unordered_set_iterator_free(unordered_set_iterator* iterator)
{
    if (!iterator)
    {
        return;
    }

    iterator->set = NULL;
    iterator->next_entry = NULL;
    free(iterator);
}

static int int_equals(void* a, void* b)
{
    int ia = (int)(intptr_t) a;
    int ib = (int)(intptr_t) b;
    return ia == ib;
}

static size_t int_hash_function(void* i)
{
    return (size_t) i;
}

static int str_equals(void* a, void* b)
{
    char* ca = (char*) a;
    char* cb = (char*) b;
    return strcmp(ca, cb) == 0;
}

static size_t str_hash_function(void* p)
{
    size_t sum;
    char* str;
    int i;

    sum = 0;
    str = (char*) p;
    i = 1;

    while (*str)
    {
        sum += *str * i;
        str++;
    }

    return sum;
}

static void unordered_set_test_add()
{
    unordered_set* set = unordered_set_alloc(1,
                                             0.5f, 
                                             int_hash_function, 
                                             int_equals);
    int i;

    puts("        unordered_set_test_add()");

    for (i = 10; i < 20; i++)
    {
        ASSERT(unordered_set_contains(set, (void*)(intptr_t) i) == FALSE); /*!*/
        ASSERT(unordered_set_add(set,      (void*)(intptr_t) i));
        ASSERT(unordered_set_contains(set, (void*)(intptr_t) i));
        ASSERT(unordered_set_is_healthy(set));
    }

    ASSERT(!unordered_set_contains(set, (void*) 9));
    ASSERT( unordered_set_contains(set, (void*) 10));
    ASSERT( unordered_set_contains(set, (void*) 19));
    ASSERT(!unordered_set_contains(set, (void*) 20));

    unordered_set_free(set);

    set = unordered_set_alloc(1, 
                              0.45, 
                              str_hash_function,
                              str_equals);

    ASSERT(!unordered_set_contains(set, "hello"));
    ASSERT(!unordered_set_contains(set, "world"));
    ASSERT(unordered_set_add(set, "world"));
    ASSERT(unordered_set_add(set, "hello"));
    ASSERT(unordered_set_contains(set, "hello"));
    ASSERT(unordered_set_contains(set, "world"));
    ASSERT(!unordered_set_contains(set, "bye"));

    ASSERT(unordered_set_is_healthy(set));

    ASSERT(unordered_set_remove(set, "hello"));
    ASSERT(!unordered_set_contains(set, "hello"));

    ASSERT(unordered_set_add(set, "repeat"));
    ASSERT(!unordered_set_add(set, "repeat"));
}

static void unordered_set_test_contains()
{
    unordered_set* set = unordered_set_alloc(3,
                                             0.7f,
                                             int_hash_function,
                                             int_equals);
    int i;

    puts("        unordered_set_test_contains()");

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        ASSERT(unordered_set_add(set, (void*)(intptr_t) i));
    }

    for (i = 99; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ASSERT(unordered_set_contains(set, (void*)(intptr_t) i));
    }

    for (i = 50; i < 100; i++)
    {
        ASSERT(unordered_set_remove(set,    (void*)(intptr_t) i));
        ASSERT(!unordered_set_contains(set, (void*)(intptr_t) i));
    }

    unordered_set_free(set);
}

static void unordered_set_test_remove()
{
    unordered_set* set = unordered_set_alloc(3,
        0.7f,
        int_hash_function,
        int_equals);

    puts("unordered_set_test_remove()");

    ASSERT(unordered_set_add(set, (void*) 1));
    ASSERT(unordered_set_add(set, (void*) 2));
    ASSERT(unordered_set_add(set, (void*) 3));
    ASSERT(3 == unordered_set_size(set));
    ASSERT(!unordered_set_add(set, (void*) 2));
    ASSERT(3 == unordered_set_size(set));

    ASSERT(unordered_set_remove(set, (void*) 2));
    ASSERT(!unordered_set_contains(set, (void*) 2));

    unordered_set_free(set);
}

static void unordered_set_test_clear()
{
    unordered_set* set = unordered_set_alloc(3,
        0.7f,
        int_hash_function,
        int_equals);

    int i;

    puts("unordered_set_test_clear()");

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        ASSERT((int) unordered_set_size(set) == i);
        unordered_set_add(set, (void*)(intptr_t) i);
    }

    unordered_set_clear(set);

    ASSERT(unordered_set_size(set) == 0);

    for (i = -100; i < 200; i++)
    {
        ASSERT(!unordered_set_contains(set, (void*)(intptr_t) i));
    }

    unordered_set_free(set);
}

static void unordered_set_test_iterator()
{
    unordered_set* set = unordered_set_alloc(
        5,
        0.6f,
        int_hash_function,
        int_equals);

    unordered_set_iterator* iterator;
    int i = 0;
    void* p;

    puts("        unordered_set_test_iterator()");

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        unordered_set_add(set, (void*)(intptr_t) i);
    }

    iterator = unordered_set_iterator_alloc(set);

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        ASSERT(unordered_set_iterator_has_next(iterator));
        ASSERT(unordered_set_contains(set, (void*)(intptr_t) i));
        ASSERT(unordered_set_iterator_next(iterator, &p));
        ASSERT(i == (intptr_t) p);
    }

    ASSERT(unordered_set_iterator_has_next(iterator) == FALSE);
}

void unordered_set_test()
{
    puts("    unordered_set_test()");

    unordered_set_test_add();
    unordered_set_test_contains();
    unordered_set_test_remove();
    unordered_set_test_clear();
    unordered_set_test_iterator();
}
```

This software belongs to [this](https://github.com/coderodde/c.graph.v2) repository).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Struct with a single pointer

Instead of making your set a struct with a single pointer (presumably to hide the implementation details of your set state), just use a forward struct declaration and force the users to only use a pointer to your set:

```
struct unordered_set;
typedef struct unordered_set unordered_set;
```

Now your set can just be what you now call `unordered_set_state` without the extra level of indirection.

#### Out of memory checks missing

You check the return value of `malloc/calloc/realloc/unordered_set_entry_alloc` in a few places, but there are several places where you don't.  Notably, `unordered_set_alloc()` and `unordered_set_add()` are missing checks.

#### Potential overflow

There is no maximum value for `load_factor`, so the following line could cause an overflow:

> ```
> set->state->max_allowed_size = (size_t)(initial_capacity * load_factor);
> ```

This could lead to `max_allowed_size` becoming some small value or even zero, which could lead to the set resizing itself on every entry added.